# Accessing mac partition from bootcamp Win7

Tags: windows, macos, bootcamp

I can access most of the folders on my mac partition but some I can't.. there is no pattern.. 
it says "xxxx is not accessible. Element not found."

Also I noticed that in some folders there is an old "snapshot".. the files have already moved but it is not reflected from the windows side... the strange thing is that I can still open some of the files that are actually no longer there (they moved to a subfolder for example).

What is going on? Can I make all my Mac files reliably accessible all the time?

thank you!
david

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution: I installed MacDrive program in my Win7.. now the Mac partition is reliably readable and I can write to it also..